# Does Java "Pass by reference" dosen't work for element present inside collections

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

I have a List which i get like following :

```java
List<MyObject> list  = complexObject.getMyObjectList();
for(final MyObject obj in list){
    // set something in obj. .............(1)
}
```

I debugged the above code and looked found out the the modified MyObject's are not reflected in the complexObject unless I do something like following..

```
complexObject.setList(list);
```

I thought Java does everything by "Pass by reference". Am i missing something. ?

Comment: Do you know the implementation of `getMyObjectList()`? Maybe it's returning a deep copy.

Comment: Java "passes references by value".

Comment: You're missing that Java doesn't pass by reference. (Some argue it does, but except for those who are plain wrong, they just extend the term "pass by reference".) See countless other questions. Let me guess, "set something in obj" is `obj = ...`?

Comment: We can't tell until we know how getMyObjectList works. It could make a list of clones.

Comment: @ Tom & delnan : Java passes primitives by value, but objects are passed by reference.

Comment: @user882196: No, references are passed by value. That doesn't mean the objects referred to are copied (you're right to imply they aren't). But pass by reference is much more powerful, it implies a lot more than having several variables, members, etc. refer to the same value. As I said, this has been discussed countless times here (and probably elsewhere). See [Is Java pass by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/395760) for the most popular instance.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of the `getMyObjectList()` function might do a deep copy of the list before returning it:

```java
protected List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
// ...
public List<MyObject> getMyObjectList() {
    List<MyObject> os = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    for (Object o: this.objects) {
      os.add(o.clone());
    }
    return os;
}
```

This is a common idiom to avoid accidentally mutating the list and/or members of the list.

Comment: But even with that idiom, one can still access the objects *inside* the list. Also, to prevent accidents it's good to use `Collections.unmodifiableList()` in that case.

Comment: This is a shallow copy. Mutating any MyObject in the list returned by `getMyObjectList()` should still mutate the object referred to from `objects`.

Comment: This wouldn't explain the OP's problem. getMyObjectList would have to clone the objects in the list as well.

Comment: @JBNizet: ah yes, I misread the question thinking it was about modifying the *list*, not the *contents* of the list.  I'll update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In java your variables like myObject holds a reference to object.

```
public MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
foo( myObject );
```

and

```
public void foo( MyClass _obj )
{
  //some code here
}
```

So if you pass myObject variable to a function, myObject's value passed by value. But the copy of myObject variable shows the same object with myObject. _obj and myObject has the same value "reference of object".